# constraint to limit number of linked fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this question that i havent found a nice way to do it.

'Insert mechanisms that enforce these rules(through checks, triggers, assertionts, etc)

3. A book cannot be linked to more than 3 fields(subjects)'

we have a book table which holds info about the book (ISBN(PK), tittle, publisher etc)
And we have another table for fields, this one holds info on the fields that are linked to be book by using ISBN as a foreign key.

What i had an idea about was making it so that we count how many times the books ISBN appears on the list, if its more than 3, it wont allow us to add a 4th. but im not sure how that is exactly done, or if theres a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, when there is not an easy way to implement what you want, you should question whether what you want is sensible. It sounds here like you are implementing an attribute-value model, which is generally used when you do not know what those attributes would be or how many there might be. In that context, stating that "three fields can be supplied, but only up to three and no more" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To the links table, add an integer column 'i' with 2 constraints:
1) unique (ISBN,i)
2) check (I between 1 and 3).

Comment: This would still require a trigger to maintain - what happens, for example, when one deletes a subject from a book?

Comment: This solution gurantees no more than 3 links per book as the PO requested. In addition there could (and should) be a foreign key defined on the book id column. No need for triggers in any case.

Comment: A unique constraint on ISBN would also guarantee no more than 3 books as the PO requested. That's not the point. It should ALSO allow AS MANY AS 3 links per book. If a book has links 1.Physics, 2.Astronomy, 3.Philosophy and then the first row is deleted, 1 becomes available again. How do you show that in your solution? How is the 'i' column maintained (other than manually)?

Comment: Don't go there. My solution enables everything it should while protecting the data integrity. The logic should be maintained by the application exactly as in the case of trying to add a 4th book. Nothing should handle it except for the application.

Comment: I disagree (and I believe many who work with databases will too). Maintain data integrity in the database whenever possible. In any case, the OP specifically stated "through checks, triggers, assertions etc." - "nothing should handle it except the application" doesn't seem to be what he was looking for.

Comment: You are now mixing between data integrity and data processing logic. Not just that the data integrity in this solution is handled by the database, the protection is done on the table level which means nothing can break it unless you interfere with the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a very simple materialized view, with `refresh fast on commit`, holding the subject count for each book. Then you can have a constraint on the count column in this materialized view. This is generally more efficient and easier to maintain than triggers - but it has the disadvantage that the constraint is checked only at commit time. This may be OK for your use case (it would probably not be OK for a table with frequent transactions).

Comment: Yes, fast refresh on commit MV is one way to go if table is relatively small and/or not very many processes refresh MV. Otherwise performance will suffer because of `JI` - contention wait events since only one process is allowed to refresh MV at a time.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov there's no way of implementing this without some kind of serialisation anyway, though.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Of course. But we are looking  at OLTP system(looks like it) where we'd have to refresh this MV every time we commit changes to the `links` table.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - Once the table is in place, the overhead should be minimal. Yes, the MV will refresh automatically after every commit but it should be quite fast since it just refreshes a count. And even if it is OLTP, it's not like logging processes for an OS or bank transactions. I would be more concerned with big transactions (initial load, perhaps acquisition of data from another database now and then, etc.) - the problem is that the check is applied only at commit time, so you either commit more often than you would like or you may have large transactions fail.

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is to use three columns in the `books` table:

subject1
   subject2
   subject3

This is not thoroughly satisfying because it does not use a junction table.  But it does meet the need.

Unfortunately, if you want to use a `BookSubjects` table, then this is more challenging.  In this case, you can add a column called `NumSubjects` to the `Books` table and a constraint that maintains the value to 3 or less.

The challenge is keeping it up-to-date.  That requires triggers for inserts and deletes.